# Trying to update PIL.ImageGrab but it isnt working

Tags: python-3.x, automation

I am trying to make a code that will call for a button to be pressed.

A function will tell which button is to be pressed. It will check if the button is a valid one (1 to 4), then will find the navigator control (custom from the app I am trying to automate, I can't find an option to order it to execute a specific), check its color according to the PIL in the memory and, if valid, press the button and wait until the button changes color to resume the code.

```
from pywinauto import application
import pywinauto
import PIL
import time
from array import *
time.clock()

def sanity_check():
    if 'app' not in globals():
        global app
        app = application.Application()
        app.connect(title="Contas a pagar")
    if 'screen' not in globals():
        global screen
        screen = PIL.ImageGrab.grab()
    if 'colorsarr' not in globals():
        global colorsarr
        colorsarr = [[(36, 210, 71),(82, 94, 105)],[(198, 62, 62),(84, 96, 107)],[(174, 218, 201),(169, 187, 207)],[(229, 13, 0),(64, 73, 81)]]

def update_screen():
    screen = PIL.ImageGrab.grab()

def click_button(number=1):
    if 1 <= number <= 4:
        number = int(number)
        buttonCoord = int((app.Contas_a_pagar.TBDBNavigator2.rectangle().right - app.Contas_a_pagar.TBDBNavigator2.rectangle().left)/4/2), int((app.Contas_a_pagar.TBDBNavigator2.rectangle().bottom - app.Contas_a_pagar.TBDBNavigator2.rectangle().top)/2)
        buttonCoord = app.Contas_a_pagar.TBDBNavigator2.rectangle().left + buttonCoord[0]*(number*2-1),buttonCoord[1]+app.Contas_a_pagar.TBDBNavigator2.rectangle().top
        if screen.getpixel(buttonCoord) == colorsarr[number-1][0]:
            pywinauto.mouse.click(button='left', coords=(buttonCoord))
            while screen.getpixel(buttonCoord) != colorsarr[number-1][1]:
                update_screen()
                continue
            return
        elif screen.getpixel(buttonCoord) == colorsarr[number-1][1]:
            print("Button unavailable")
            return
        else:
            print("Color check button " + str(number))
            return

def automate_things():
    sanity_check()
    print(time.clock())
    for i in range(-3,10):
        click_button(i)
    print(time.clock())

automate_things()
```

My problem is that my function `update_screen` should change what is stored in the var `screen` but it isn't, making the while loop infinite. Even if I put a window on the position it grabs the pixel color, it keeps getting the other color.

The `colorsarr` array has on the 0-index the "pressable" color and in the 1-index the "unpressable" color

This is my first python code, so probably I am doing something wrong. When complete, I will try code review for better code. While suggestions for better coding are welcome, the focus is just why the screen var isn't updating.